# Can't install Arnet mondem 3G on Ubuntu

Tags: 3g

I can't install Arnet Modem 3g on my Ubuntu.

There are a tutorial [Here](http://www.taringa.net/posts/linux/10581710/Instalar-Modem-Arnet-3G-en-Ubuntu.html) But when I start:

```
vitor@vitor-hp:~/Downloads/Arnet$ ls
autorun.sh  install_linux  Linux  SysConfig.dat
vitor@vitor-hp:~/Downloads/Arnet$ sudo sh autorun.sh 
autorun.sh: 6: autorun.sh: /install_linux: not found
```

I already copied all files on my notebook.

But when I run:

```
vitor@vitor-hp:~/Downloads/Arnet$ sudo sh autorun.sh
```

Appears

```
autorun.sh: 6: autorun.sh: /install_linux: not found
```

But this file exit

```
vitor@vitor-hp:~/Downloads/Arnet$ ls
autorun.sh  install_linux  Linux  SysConfig.dat
```

And I already change the permission too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is [here](http://www.vivaolinux.com.br/topico/Classificados-de-empregos-Linux/MODEM-3G-USB-HUAWEI-E303-NO-UBUNTU-Precise-Pangolin-12042-1) (in portuguese)

To install according to Arnet never works on linux.

Have to install manually.